# Created nodes and relationships lost when restarting Neo4j Browser Enterprise edition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create some nodes and relationships in Neo4j browser. But when I restart the browser, I seem to lose them completely.

I did try changing the dbms.active_database in the conf file. I see the new database created in the database folder but the browser starts as having no data. Is there any additional command to maybe start the browser with the database specified in dbms.active_database? Should I not be changing dbms.active_database at all? Are the nodes and relationships I create stored to the dbms.active_database?

```
neo4j start

CREATE (:FooBar)

neo4j restart

MATCH (node:FooBar)
RETURN node
-- no nodes and relationships found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Neo4j currently supports only one active database at a time.**

You are creating nodes and relationships in one database(active database at the time of creation) and then changing the active database to some other database.

When you change the active database then if the database already exists Neo4j starts it with the previous data else it creates a new empty database.

**You're right, you should not change the active database.**